# Can I remove the "Item successfully added to your cart" popup?

Tags: commerce

Can I removed the *Item successfully added to your cart* popup in Drupal Commerce?

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Goto: **/admin/config/workflow/rules**
and **disable** '**Display an Add to Cart message**' Rule.

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: disable it as discribed by @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. To customize it you could you can clone it. Remove the action that comes with it and use the "Show a message on the site" action instead. Then enable.